# NGINX / PHP-FPM: Ajax slow first request, good next ones

Tags: jquery, ajax, nginx, php

- The CMS is `Elxis`, which comes from a variant of Joomla (PHP).

  - The server is running `nGinx` with `PHP-FPM`
  - All requests get logged and executed, eventually, B U T!!!

When firing a specific request via the URL bar, the request gets executed immediately. However, when fired via ajax (through jQuery), the same request has a very strange behaviour.

Namely: First request (on a media manager), to view picture details, is to be fired with Ajax. It is logged on the browser, but not on the server... Not just yet... After some good 40-50 seconds, the request appears on the server and then it is responded immediately.

All following requests are executed immediately, no problem. Only the first one is rough..

I am in trouble because there is not any error logged anywhere: Everything seems sane, except for the lag of the first request to reach the server...

It is not routing (the site is already up and requests have been served), it is not resolution (the ip is in my /etc/hosts file).

And to add a little cherry on top of the cake, trying to capture packets (tcpdump) on the server produces no output: The request is not here yet... 
Tried on client too: no output - for at least 40 secs...

It's all on the browser, developer console shows no error, just a pending request.

Does any of this ring a bell to anyone?

```
The server:
nginx version: nginx/1.6.2
PHP 5.6.7-1 (cli)
PHP 5.6.7-1 (fpm-fcgi)
```

jQuery version 1.11
The client: tried on Firefox 39 (ubuntu) and Chromium 41

Comment: Duplicate posted on Server Fault [NGINX / PHP-FPM: Ajax slow first request, good next ones](http://serverfault.com/questions/681861/nginx-php-fpm-ajax-slow-first-request-good-next-ones).

Comment: @Paul, stackoverflow is for code, server fault is for services. Please, help me chose which one is the case and I will withdraw the irrelevent one of the two posts

Comment: did you find out? I'm having a very similar problem

Comment: I'll have to look up, it was work for a friend and I haven't heard from that project ever since... I'll get you posted.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have same problem and i'm stuck... Thanks!

Comment: I saw a similar issue that would only manifest in Chrome and was related to infinite scrolling.  I think there was another bounty for that a few weeks/months ago.  Is it infinite scrolling that's potentially at stake in your code?

Comment: can you pls share the sample url of your application to reproduce the problem

Comment: @Orchid, No because it would be in the backend, administration of the CMS. Anyhow, this is a project I don't deal with for quite some time now.

Comment: @RubyRacer , Have you tried using the new JQuery plugin?

Comment: Is it possilbe that you send a lot of data with your rquest? I guess not, but maybe the following helps:

convert your data to json JSON.stringify(data);
Add the contenttype 'application/json' to your ajax request
make sure your server interprets the incoming data as json

Comment: People, I am off this one for some time. I am not the one who set the bounty.

Comment: (I know OP will be notified of this but there's no way to avoid it). The original question indicates that the request appears in the browser log but not the server logs, however we need to know at which point the server logs the request. Is it as soon as it hits it or is it the FPM log? If it's the former then the problem is unlikely to be on the server end but rather intermediate.

Comment: @apokryfos, I only said that because I was tagged by praneeth. I don't have a problem being notified. To the question part, there was no network activity detected serverside whatsoever. I used tcpdump to capture tcp activity. There was none, and then, a long time later there was. All this is described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar kind of problem and i ended up increasing number of php-fpm workers. I used the following settings in www.conf (pool.d) to solve the problem i was facing. I had an analytics server setup which was tracking pageviews and there was a delay of 15-20s in API recording the pageviews. Tuning the following settings solved my problem, maybe it might help you.

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```